# How to set the Notification Area in Android?

Tags: android

When a notification arrives it hides the network signal and battery status icons.

Is there any possibility to show the notification without hiding the network icons?

Comment: One question mark is more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a notification arrives it hides the network signal and battery status icons.

For about 1-2 seconds, while the ticker text is being displayed.

> Is there any possibility to show the notification without hiding the network icons?

AFAIK, no. You could try an empty/null ticker text and see what happens -- I haven't tried that.

Comment: when i set ticker text=null i got that.But i need to display only 5 chars  with default network and battery status icon also